# Creating Text Stream Using Spring WebFlux

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I've been using Spring WebFlux to create a text stream, here is the code.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class ReactiveServer {

    private static final String FILE_PATH = "c:/test/";


    @GetMapping(produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE, value = "/events")
    Flux<String> events() {

        Flux<String> eventFlux = Flux.fromStream(Stream.generate(() -> FileReader.readFile()));

        Flux<Long> durationFlux = Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(500));

        return Flux.zip(eventFlux, durationFlux).map(Tuple2::getT1);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(ReactiveServer.class, args);

    }

}
```

**When I access the /events url on the browser I get this, that's almost what I want to get:**

data:{"type":"HystrixCommand","name":"GetConsumerCommand","group":"ConsumerRemoteGroup","currentTime":1542379993662,"isCircuitBreakerOpen":false,"errorPercentage":0,"errorCount":0,"requestCount":0,"rollingCountBadRequests":0}

data:{"type":"HystrixCommand","name":"GetConsumerCommand","group":"ConsumerRemoteGroup","currentTime":1542379994203,"isCircuitBreakerOpen":false,"errorPercentage":0,"errorCount":0,"requestCount":2,"rollingCountBadRequests":0}

data:{"type":"HystrixCommand","name":"GetConsumerCommand","group":"ConsumerRemoteGroup","currentTime":1542379994706,"isCircuitBreakerOpen":false,"errorPercentage":0,"errorCount":0,"requestCount":2,"rollingCountBadRequests":0}

data:{"type":"HystrixCommand","name":"GetConsumerCommand","group":"ConsumerRemoteGroup","currentTime":1542379995213,"isCircuitBreakerOpen":false,"errorPercentage":0,"errorCount":0,"requestCount":3,"rollingCountBadRequests":0}

**What I need to do is to insert a "ping:" in between  iterations to get:**

ping:

data:{"type":"HystrixCommand","name":"GetConsumerCommand","group":"ConsumerRemoteGroup","currentTime":1542379993662,"isCircuitBreakerOpen":false,"errorPercentage":0,"errorCount":0,"requestCount":0,"rollingCountBadRequests":0}

data:{"type":"HystrixCommand","name":"GetConsumerCommand","group":"ConsumerRemoteGroup","currentTime":1542379994203,"isCircuitBreakerOpen":false,"errorPercentage":0,"errorCount":0,"requestCount":2,"rollingCountBadRequests":0}

ping:

data:{"type":"HystrixCommand","name":"GetConsumerCommand","group":"ConsumerRemoteGroup","currentTime":1542379994706,"isCircuitBreakerOpen":false,"errorPercentage":0,"errorCount":0,"requestCount":2,"rollingCountBadRequests":0}

data:{"type":"HystrixCommand","name":"GetConsumerCommand","group":"ConsumerRemoteGroup","currentTime":1542379995213,"isCircuitBreakerOpen":false,"errorPercentage":0,"errorCount":0,"requestCount":3,"rollingCountBadRequests":0}

**But, the best I could get was:**

data: ping:

data:{"type":"HystrixCommand","name":"GetConsumerCommand","group":"ConsumerRemoteGroup","currentTime":1542379993662,"isCircuitBreakerOpen":false,"errorPercentage":0,"errorCount":0,"requestCount":0,"rollingCountBadRequests":0}

data:{"type":"HystrixCommand","name":"GetConsumerCommand","group":"ConsumerRemoteGroup","currentTime":1542379994203,"isCircuitBreakerOpen":false,"errorPercentage":0,"errorCount":0,"requestCount":2,"rollingCountBadRequests":0}

data: ping:

data:{"type":"HystrixCommand","name":"GetConsumerCommand","group":"ConsumerRemoteGroup","currentTime":1542379994706,"isCircuitBreakerOpen":false,"errorPercentage":0,"errorCount":0,"requestCount":2,"rollingCountBadRequests":0}

data:{"type":"HystrixCommand","name":"GetConsumerCommand","group":"ConsumerRemoteGroup","currentTime":1542379995213,"isCircuitBreakerOpen":false,"errorPercentage":0,"errorCount":0,"requestCount":3,"rollingCountBadRequests":0}

**Does anyone know of a way to what I need?**

Answer (score 1):

You could try returning a `Flux<ServerSentEvent>` and specify the type of event you're trying to send. Like this:

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping(produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE, path = "/events")
    Flux<ServerSentEvent> events() {
        Flux<String> events = Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(200)).map(String::valueOf);
        Flux<ServerSentEvent<String>> sseData = events.map(event -> ServerSentEvent.builder(event).build());
        Flux<ServerSentEvent<String>> ping = Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(500))
                .map(l -> ServerSentEvent.builder("").event("ping").build());
        return Flux.merge(sseData, ping);
    }
}
```

With that code snippet, I'm getting the following output:

```
$ http --stream :8080/events
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/event-stream;charset=UTF-8
transfer-encoding: chunked

data:0

data:1

event:ping
data:

data:2

data:3

data:4

event:ping
data:
```

Which is consistent with [Server Sent Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events). Is the `ping:` prefix something specific to Hystrix? If it is, I don't think this is consistent with the SSE spec and that it's something supported in Spring Framework.

Comment: HI, Brian, thanks for you answer. What I'm trying to do is to create a data stream in exactly the way the Hystrix Dashboard expects it to be. I think it uses the "ping:" String between events as a kind of separation. So your answer gives me something like:

So what I really need is just to print that "ping:" at the beginning of an event. But without the "data:".

Like this:

ping:

Not like this:

data:ping:

Comment: that's what my sample is doing: sending SSE events of type data (the default) and ping. They're currently just interleaved and the ping events are scheduled with a specific duration between them.

Comment: When I run your code "ping:" doesn't print. I get this:


`data:{"type":"HystrixCommand","name":"GetConsumerCommand","group":"ConsumerRemoteGroup","currentTime":1542382826545}

data:{"type":"HystrixCommand","name":"GetConsumerCommand","group":"ConsumerRemoteGroup","currentTime":1542382827046}

data:{"type":"HystrixCommand","name":"GetConsumerCommand","group":"ConsumerRemoteGroup","currentTime":1542382827547}

data:{"type":"HystrixCommand","name":"GetConsumerCommand","group":"ConsumerRemoteGroup","currentTime":1542382828049}`

Comment: Hi Brian, it's specific to Hystrix. It's a shame I can't do it with WebFlux. I close to a solution using reactivex. Thank you very much for you efforts.